# What is the difference in running script with ./

Tags: command-line, scripts

What is the difference between running the script by calling directly its name and
calling the script by adding a with prefix of './' .
I can't find any difference in run time.

Comment: What do you mean by saying "calling directly its name"

Comment: suppose the script name is testScript then diff between ./testScript  and testScript

Comment: See added info in my answer.

Comment: See: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/136547/38906

Comment: See also http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/4459/22005 for why.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the scripts directory isn't in your PATH, and . (the current directory) is not in the PATH either, you can run the script using `./` as shown below

```
./script_name.sh
```

Use the script file name to run it either by using it’s relative path or absolute path as shown below:

```
cd /home/user
./script_name.sh
```

OR

```
/home/user/script_name.sh
```

Comment: There is one minor difference that the script sees, which in a perfect world wouldn't matter, but sometimes does. If the script is looking at `$0` to see how it was invoked, it might see `./testscript` or `/home/user/testscript` (depending on the path). Of course, this is bad coding practice and the coder should use `"\`basename $0\`"` (or  `"${0##*/}"`), but I've seen some scripts use the full path because the writer "knows" the script will always be at that path.

Answer (score 7):

The difference is that your current working directory would have to contain the script that you'd like to execute.

In this case, the dot stands for current directory, the slash does it's normal delimiter job, then the name of the script follows.

If a script was in the directory above your current working directory you could execute it using ../

It's usually bad practice to call a script, from within another script with ./ , as if one scipt is moved, it loses it's reference to the location of the other script.

Comment: ./testScript.sh means current working directory would have to contain the testScript.sh ?

Comment: :) forgot to do that